# c assignment operator =

Tags: c

Can anyone pl. explain how the following c program works: 
Specifically how function 'fun' is assigned to `(*p)() = fun`; I need to know how compiler compiles this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(); /* function prototype */

int main()
{
    int (*p)() = fun;
    (*p)();
    return 0;
}
int fun()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up "function pointers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each function exists in memory somewhere. The statement:

```
int (*p)() = fun;
```

is assigning the memory location of the function fun to p. Then the line:

```
(*p)();
```

is calling the function that exists at the memory location that p is pointing to.

The Interweb is full of info on "function pointers."

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code generated by `gcc` (with `-O0`):

```
    movl    $_fun, -4(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    call    *%eax
```

It stores the address of the `fun` function in a variable in the stack and then simply indirectly calls this address.

Comment: Is this way the fastest call? Faster than f(); ?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık of course not and with optimizations enabled `gcc` directly issues a `call    _fun` with this program.